# Please help me change my LUKS password

Tags: luks, disk-encryption

I have a terrible LUKS password and if that wasn't enough I also have to type it blindly with the wrong locale keyboard in a headless server. I want to change it to something else but I have a very hard time to find the correct way to do it.

First some info:

```
root@koma-server:~# lsblk --fs
NAME                          FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
loop0                         squashfs                                                 /snap/core/11993
loop2                         squashfs                                                 /snap/core/12603
sda                                                                                    
├─sda1                                                                                 
├─sda2                        ext4              38a1a180-34a0-423e-a4ed-e20f4fc4c7a1   /boot
└─sda3                        crypto_LUKS       c83ef178-d95b-4c38-a47b-8335446c67f3   
  └─sda3_crypt                LVM2_member       ftenuW-YgVf-9OSn-xHve-Glpq-ttCX-QOAZ3j 
    ├─koma--server--vg-root   ext4              d4a3ee37-bd00-4924-adf5-13f2ee2407cd   /
    └─koma--server--vg-swap_1 swap              ce8dd4b0-1c0e-4610-a7a6-ecd8462ff5a9   [SWAP]
sdb                                                                                    
└─sdb1                        crypto_LUKS       0ecff03a-c4f1-4067-b6bd-6e0b94618fb3
```

```
root@koma-server:~# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              390M  1.1M  389M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/koma--server--vg-root  2.7T  189G  2.4T   8% /
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                         100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11993
/dev/sda2                          705M  291M  364M  45% /boot
/dev/loop2                         111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12603
tmpfs                              390M     0  390M   0% /run/user/1000
```

When the system boots up I get asked to enter the decryption password. I assume this is for koma--server--vg-root. I tried around some guidelines / howtos on the internet but I think I'm just a blind chicken poking around my system (I haven't set it up...), so please help me, thanks!

Let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: `sudo cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/sda3`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank youuuuuu, it worked!